# Imagem de Background não aparece quando executo o projeto

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um projeto JSF+Primefaces e tenho um css que coloca um background:

```
<h:body 
    style="background-image: url('../images/textura.jpg');">
```

Quando eu executo a página funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu dou um executar no projeto a imagem não carrega, ela só carrega após alguma operação ser realizada.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente é o caminho da imagem. Recomendo deixa imagens na pasta resources do sistema. Exemplo : `resources/images`. Assim usando o `#{resource[]}` ele pega o caminho raiz para a pasta. Exemplo:

```
 background-image: url("#{resource['images/textura.jpg']}");
```

Comment: Essa pasta resources sou eu que devo criar? ou é o SRC?

Comment: E quando eu coloco isso dentro de um `style` da erro

Comment: eu criei uma classe css e coloquei esse código. mas se for dentro de um `style`, tente usar esse `style="background-image: url('#{resource['images/textura.jpg']}')"`. Eu criei a pasta manualmente.

Comment: Criei a pasta resource no WebContent, e coloquei o código, a imagem não aparece

Comment: problema resolvido, fiz uma modificação e funcionou:
`background-image:url(#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/textura.jpg);`